# Restarting a service after looped commands on multiple servers

Tags: ansible

I poked around a bit here but didn't see anything that quite matched up to what I am trying to accomplish, so here goes.

So I've put together my first Ansible playbook which opens or closes one or more ports on the firewall of  one or more hosts, for one or more specified IP addresses. Works great so far. But what I want to do is restart the firewall service after all the tasks for a given host are complete (with no errors, of course).

NOTE: The `hostvars/localhost` references just hold `vars_prompt` input from the user in a task list above this one. I store prompted data in `hosts: localhost` build a dynamic host list based on what the user entered, and then have a separate task list to actually do the work.

So:

```
- name: Execute remote firewall-cmd for each host in "dynamically created host group"
  hosts: dynamically_created_host_list
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        hostList: "{{hostvars['localhost']['hostList']}}"

    - set_fact:
        portList: "{{hostvars['localhost']['portList']}}"

    - set_fact:
        portStateRequested: "{{hostvars['localhost']['portStateRequested']}}"

    - set_fact:
        portState: "{{hostvars['localhost']['portState']}}"

    - set_fact:
        remoteIPs: "{{hostvars['localhost']['remoteIPs']}}"

    - name: Invoke firewall-cmd remotely
      firewalld:

         .. module-specific stuff here ...

      with_nested:
        - "{{ remoteIPs.split(',') }}"
        - "{{ portList.split(',') }}"
      register: requestStatus
```

In my original version of the script, which only did 1 port for 1 host for 1 IP, I just did:

```
    - name: Reload firewalld
      when: requestStatus.changed
      systemd:
      name: firewalld
      state: reloaded
```

But I don't think that will work as easily here because of the nesting. For example. Let's say I want to open port 9999 for a remote IP address of 1.1.1.1 on 10 different hosts. And let's say the 5th host has an error for some reason. I may not want to restart the firewall service at that point.

Actually, now that I think about it, I guess that in that scenario, there would be 4 new entries to the firewall config, and 6 that didn't take because of the error. Now I'm wondering if I need to track the successes, and have a `rescue` block within the Playbook to back those entries that did go through.

Grrr.... any ideas? Sorry, new to Ansible here. Plus, I hate YAML for things like this. :D

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like what you are looking for is what Ansible call [handlers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change).

> As we’ve mentioned, modules should be idempotent and can relay when
>   they have made a change on the remote system. Playbooks recognize this
>   and have a basic event system that can be used to respond to change.
>
> These ‘notify’ actions are triggered at the end of each block of tasks
>   in a play, and will only be triggered once even if notified by
>   multiple different tasks.
>
> For instance, multiple resources may indicate that apache needs to be
>   restarted because they have changed a config file, but apache will
>   only be bounced once to avoid unnecessary restarts.

Note that `handlers` are simply a pair of

1. A `notify` attribute on one or multiple tasks
2. A handler, with a `name` matching your above mentioned `notify` attribute

So your playbook should look like

```
- name: Execute remote firewall-cmd for each host in "dynamically created host group"
  hosts: dynamically_created_host_list
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:  
    # set_fact removed for concision

    - name: Invoke firewall-cmd remotely
      firewalld:
        #   .. module-specific stuff here ...
      with_nested:
        - "{{ remoteIPs.split(',') }}"
        - "{{ portList.split(',') }}"
      notify: Reload firewalld

handlers:
  - name: Reload firewalld
    systemd:
      name: firewalld
      state: reloaded
```

Comment: Ah ok, I think I get where you are going with that. So, in your snippet above, once the task look completes, it would invoke the handler. Makes sense. Now, of course, I have to figure out how to determine success or failure of the firewall command. It would be awesome if you could register an array (one per host) rather than a scalar.

Comment: @incursio you could use [wait_for](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html) to determine if your ip + port are open as expected

Comment: That is an interesting concept, and probably a better empirical test than just making sure the firewall-cmd returned successfully. I may explore that, thanks!

Comment: I ended up going with the handler approach. I did some more research and handlers only get notified for hosts that have been flagged as "changed". Of course, there is still a chance, however remote, that a given module could munge up a config file, and the reload/restart of a service would fail, so I am planning to explore rescue blocks soon.